# Comment approval permission to non-admin user

Tags: 6, comments

I have three accounts in my Drupal 6 site:

- admin (which is admin)
- moderator
- moderator2 (which is authenticated role defined)

Now I want to give permission to the moderator2 to approve comments just like I did from admin account by only going to `/admin/content/comment`. How can I do that?

Comment: Does going to `/admin/user/permissions` and ticking the box that says `administer comments` for the `moderator2` user do what you want it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take that "moderator2" is a username name used for a user account. In that case, if you want to give to moderator2 the permission to administer comments, then you have to associate the user account with a role you only give to those users you want to be able to administer comments, then you visit the page on admin/user/permissions, and select "administer comments" for that role.

[image: screenshot]

In this case, I called the role "comments moderator" but I could have chosen another name.

If "moderator2" is a role name, then on the page at admin/user/permissions you see something similar to what shown in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

The permission is the same as before.

**P.S.** The only permission for which you are interested is "administer comments." The other permissions don't influence that one, and users with a specific role would be able to approve comments, even without to have (for example) the permission to access comments.
The only permission associated with the page at admin/content/comment is "administer comments."

```
  $items['admin/content/comment'] = array(
    'title' => 'Comments', 
    'description' => 'List and edit site comments and the comment moderation queue.', 
    'page callback' => 'comment_admin', 
    'access arguments' => array('administer comments'), 
    'file' => 'comment.admin.inc',
  );
```